# Add a background image to a tailwinds css section

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I am trying to figure out how to add a background image to a Tailwinds CSS template section.

The tailwind docs say to extend the theme, with a defined image, which I have done in my tailwind.config.js as follows:

extend: {
backgroundImage: {
'ttuPattern': "url('/images/ttu.png')"
},

I want to use that image as the background of a section.

```
<section
      id="ttu"
      aria-label="Features for investing all your money"
      className="bg-gray-900 py-20 sm:py-32 ALSO TRIED IT HERE bg-cover" style="background-image: ttuPattern height: 100%"
      
    >
      <Container>
        <div className="mx-auto max-w-2xl lg:mx-0 lg:max-w-3xl bg-cover" style="background-image: ttuPattern height: 100%">
```

The image doesn't display in my section at all.

How can I use a bg image in tailwind css?

Comment: have you tried using it as tailwind class this way: `bg-ttuPattern`?

Comment: Yes- it doesn't work as:     className="bg-gray-900 py-20 sm:py-32 bg-ttuPattern"

Comment: hmm, have you double checked that the path to image is correct? If i put `<div class="bg-gray-900 py-20 sm:py-32 bg-test bg-cover"></div>` to tailwind playground and extend backgroundImage in config with random image from web it works just fine

Comment: the difference for me is that it's className rather than class. I have tried defining the image as both url...and '@/images/....  Neither works

Comment: It's also not using the color themes I defined in extend in tailwind.config.js - so there must be a bigger issue.

Comment: You can try to update post with more information, like contents of tailwind.config.js . Maybe you are missing `content` in config or something.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `bg-ttuPattern` in [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) attribute because it just takes less. In the new version 3, you can use [arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#arbitrary-values) if you're going to use the image once:

```html
<div class="bg-[url('../public/images/tailwind.png')]"></div>
```

And I've fixed some syntax issues in `tailwind.config.js`.

##### Code:

###### Structure:

```html
<section class="bg-gray-900 bg-ttuPattern bg-cover py-20 sm:py-32">
  <!-- Your content goes here! -->
</section>
```

###### Config:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        ttuPattern: "url('https://via.placeholder.com/600x200.png')",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

See [playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/kNRf766XL2).

Comment: thank you for sharing your proposed solutions. I tried saving the image as a png to a folder in public/images (as ttu.png) and then tried using, with the exception that I used className instead of class. I get an error that says Module not found: Can't resolve '../public/images/ttu.png'. I don't know how to define the url as a https address to be able to use the config style proposed in your config example, but could not get it to render using an address to a file inside my code.

Comment: @Mel There's no difference between `class` and `className` I guess you're using [Next](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17639) or Vue? Anyway, try to use arbitrary values which should be easy as `<div class="bg-[url('./tailwind.png')]"></div>`?

Comment: arbitrary values are what I tried using and which generated the error described above.

Comment: @Mel And does [this thread](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17639) fixes the problem by chance?